# event tracking for php print in google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, event-tracking

Below is a segment of php code from my website. I have google analytics plugged in and i'd like to use event tracking or something else in analytics to show me when a user ends up seeing the statement below shown on the webpage. This statement occurs when the user enters a non matching suburb into a form on the home page. Im using POST method so the URL is not unique unfortunately.

```
if($row_cnt == 0)
{
    PRINT "<p align='middle'>Unfortunately we do not have an online price for the     suburb you entered.</p><p align='middle'>We may still provide our service to your area though.</p><p align='middle'>Please call our office on xxxxx to make an over the phone booking.</p>"; 
 }

else
```

Comment: You need to read Google Analytics Documentation, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: A logging system might be a better approach. I and my company use and love Loggly (http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) which is free for 200 MB/day for 7 days of storage. It's incredibly extensible via AlertBirds and has libraries in pretty much every language and system on earth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to simple place the event tracking code inside the PRINT function so that it fires when it is printed on page. Something like this might work, but you'll have to test

```
if($row_cnt == 0)
{
    PRINT "<p align='middle'>Unfortunately we do not have an online price for the     suburb you entered.</p><p align='middle'>We may still provide our service to your area though.</p><p align='middle'>Please call our office on xxxxx to make an over the phone booking.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'eventCategory', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel ']);
</script>"; 
 }
 else
```

Or to be cleaner you could simply put the event code off page and call it by the ID of the element. In which case I would wrap the entire thing into a div, give the div an ID and then use the `getElementById("DIV-ID");` method.

Let me know if it works.